# When pinching in UIScrollView the image just jumps down and left and then the whole ScrollView freezes

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, scrollview

So i have a scrollView and an image view inside and everything works great(scrolling) until i try to pinch to zoom when the whole picture just jumps to the down and left and stays the same size but when i lift my finger the scrollView just freezes, even the scrolling stops working. Here is the code:

```
class ScrollViewViewController: ViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageView = UIImageView()
var image = UIImage() {
    didSet {imageView.image = image}
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size)
    scrollView?.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    scrollView?.delegate = self
    scrollView?.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
    scrollView?.maximumZoomScale = 2
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
}
```

Anyone sees any potential problems?

Comment: Your question heading and content are two different thing.

Comment: Woops, sorry i just fixed that.